# Oraclize API not returning anything in Morden testnet

Tags: go-ethereum, testnets, oracles, morden

I use Geth 1.3.6 and a Morden testnet.
I am trying to test the Oraclize API for my Ethereum smart contracts.

First, I have compiled and deployed the simple smart contracts as DieselPricePeg.sol and PriceTicker.sol, also using dev.oraclize.it/.
I have not any correct output by query, even I don't get id by oraclize_query.

One of the two smart contract is visible at the following link: https://github.com/oraclize/ethereum-examples/blob/master/solidity/DieselPricePeg.sol

(I think that the problem is not in the code of smart Contract.)

Any suggestions?

Comment: Without seeing your contract, and without more detail on what's going wrong (link to transaction IDs, if you can), there's no way anyone's going to have enough information to answer.

Comment: I edited my question.

Comment: You still need to give us a more detailed description of what you're doing, what happens, what you expected to happen, what error messages you get (if any), and so forth. This may be helpful: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Thomas from Oraclize here. As others have said, you are not giving enough details, can you disclose the ethereum address you have deployed your contract to? I would suggest you to come to [our gitter channel](https://gitter.im/oraclize/ethereum-api) for Oraclize-specific questions as this would be much more interactive and easy to sort out.

Comment: If you are using the DieselPricePeg example contract you need either to comment the line `update(60*10)` in `__callback` or to have enough funds in the contract balance as the second oraclize_query [comes at a cost](http://docs.oraclize.it/#free-calls).

Comment: Hi Thomas. In "our gitter channel", I found my answer. Thank you. (My solution was to comment the line update(60*10))

Comment: If you found the answer, could you post an answer with a summary of what was wrong and how you fixed it, for future askers?

Comment: @ThomasBertani Since OP hasn't posted their answer, which sounds exactly like yours, would you like to post/explain the answer?

Answer (score 2):

**TL;DR: The contract didn't have enough balance to pay the Oraclize fee required after the first call to Oraclize.**

Going to explain this answer since it was never explained:

OP was attempting to use the following Oraclize demo contract:

```
import "dev.oraclize.it/api.sol";

contract DieselPricePeg is usingOraclize {

    uint public DieselPriceUSD;


    function DieselPricePeg() {
        oraclize_setProof(proofType_TLSNotary | proofStorage_IPFS);
        update(0); // first check at contract creation
    }

    function __callback(bytes32 myid, string result, bytes proof) {
        if (msg.sender != oraclize_cbAddress()) throw;
        DieselPriceUSD = parseInt(result, 2); // let's save it as $ cents
        // do something with the USD Diesel price
        update(60*10); // schedule another check in 10 minutes
    }

    function update(uint delay) {
        oraclize_query(delay, "URL", "xml(https://www.fueleconomy.gov/ws/rest/fuelprices).fuelPrices.diesel");
    }

}
```

The constructor calls `update(0)`, which tells `oraclize_query` to return the value as quickly as possible (just initializing it). When `oraclize_query` calls `__callback`, the data is parsed and `__callback` calls `update(60*10)`. The **first** call made to Oraclize from any contract (in the constructor or not) is **free**. Any **further calls** come at a cost and require the contract (or account) to carry a balance. `__callback` is calling `update(60*10)`, which **will not return a value if the contract is not carrying any balance**.